# Convert CKRecord in NSData

Tags: swift, nsdata, ckrecord

I am trying to store a CKRecord on my NSUserDefaults. But as far as I can see the defaults wont take CKRecords, but will take NSData.

I am looking for help on how to convert my CKRecord onto NSData. Is it possible to be done?

**To NSData**

```
func set_activeLinkRequest(record: CKRecord) {
        print("PublicUsers - set_activeLinkRequest \(record)")

        var data = NSData()

        // convert the record into NSData

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "activeLinkRequest")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
```

**Back to CKRecord**

```
func get_activeLinkRequest() -> CKRecord {
    let record = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("activeLinkRequest") as! NSData

    // convert NSDate into CKRecord

    print("PublicUsers = get_activeLinkRequest \(value)")
    return record
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, hope it help others.

**CKRecord to NSData to NSUserDefaults**

```
func set_activeLinkRequest(record: CKRecord) {
    print("PublicUsers - set_activeLinkRequest \(record)")

    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(record)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "activeLinkRequest")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

**NSUserDefaults to NSData to CKRecord**

```
func get_activeLinkRequest() -> CKRecord {

     let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("activeLinkRequest") as! NSData      
     let record = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! CKRecord

     print("PublicUsers = get_activeLinkRequest \(record)")
     return record
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. above solution help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
func setActiveLinkRequest(record: CKRecord) {
    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: record, requiringSecureCoding: false)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "activeLinkRequest")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func getActiveLinkRequest() -> CKRecord? {

    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "activeLinkRequest") as? Data else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let record = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: CKRecord.self, from: data)
        return record
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```